# Is it good practice to use razor pages directives inside javascript <script> tags to pass model property values?

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm developing a web app using asp.net core MVC and I've found my self using razor pages directives to pass model property values to javascript for further manipulation of the page. Is this ok? Should I worry of security concerns? If so, could some one explain?

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice to use razor pages directives inside javascript  tags to pass model property values

Yes.When you use js to call razor page handler,it is sending a request to razor page handler in js,and getting the response of it.So it is safe.

Here is a demo using ajax to get data from handler:

```
function Test() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '?handler=Test',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    //getting data here
                },
                error: function (result) {
                   
                }

            });
        }
```

handler:

```
public xxx OnGetTest(){
            //return data here
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I was referring  to passing model properties to javascript variables using the razor page directives like so:

`let cart = "@(Model.Cart)";`

Comment: Yes,you can do like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to pass data in javascript for manipulation in your Razor pages. But if you're passing some sensitive information like (ID, password, email, etc.) then make sure to encrypt it. Because anyone can easily find this information in the browser's console if it is passing through Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using Razor inside  tags to pass model property values is generally not considered a good practice. While it may work in some cases, it can lead to code that is difficult to maintain, understand, and debug.

Mixing server-side Razor code with client-side JavaScript can make the code harder to read and maintain, as it blurs the line between server-side and client-side responsibilities.

Also, I am currently working on an application that is required to apply CSP policy to prevent inline javascript. Of course migrating all razor dependent code is almost impossible and now costs us a huge rework